# Disable completion of substrings in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I to disable the following behaviour:

```
cd deo<Tab>
--> cd Videos
```

I'm using zsh 5.3.1 on macOS, with oh-my-zsh.

Comment: What's your setup?  Are you using `oh-my-zsh`, `Prezto`, `zim`, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

This comes from the [matchers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Matching-Control) which are configured with the [`matcher-list`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-matcher_002dlist_002c-completion-style) completion style.

Set the matcher list to something that doesn't include prefix addition, for example plain completion-at-cursor:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list ''
```

This needs to go in your `.zshrc` after the oh-my-zsh code, since oh-my-zsh is what turns on prefix completion.

Even with the default settings, if you do want to get completion from a substring sometimes, you can request it explicitly by putting a `*` wildcard where you want to allow completion to insert something:

```
cd *deoTab
```

If you want the behavior to depend on the command, you can specify which command the `zstyle` setting applies to by using a more precise [context](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Overview-2). For example, to turn this off only when completing directories:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:complete:*:_dirs:*' matcher-list ''
```